# API response to file

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm receiving this response from an API and I'm trying to convert it to a file in Java, but when the file is created it says that the file is corrupted.
[image]

Here's the code that i'm using.

```
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(serverUrl)
            .queryParam("fileID", fileID);

    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.toUriString(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            entity,
            String.class);


    System.out.println("Bytes de response body: " + response.getBody());





    saveFile("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\" + fileName,body);

}

private static void saveFile(String path, String octetStream) throws IOException{
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)){
        fos.write(octetStream.getBytes());
    }
```

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This could be related, I see the response seems to be a binary file, you are converting the response of the API into a String, hence you are imposing some convention on how to read the bytes, you can try to have the response as `byte[]` or as an `InputStream` without transforming any byte into a string

Comment: That was exactly my issue, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
I changed the response entity type from String to byte []

```
   ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.toUriString(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            entity,
            byte[].class);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).